# Question on notation: What does $0 \leq M \leq 1$ mean for a bounded operator $M$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $M\colon \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be bounded linear operator.

I am working through a paper by Roger Godement from the 1950's. In one section (given the above ingredients) an assumption is made that "$0 \leq M \leq 1$".

Now I am wondering what is meant by this notation, since I never have seen it. I imagine it could mean that the spectrum of $M$ can be assumed to be contained in $[0,1]$. My question is, whether this is (or has been, at the time) a common notation?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means
$$
0=(0x,x)\leq (Mx,x)\leq (Ix,x)=(x,x)\qquad \forall x\in H.
$$
Implicitly, this also says that $M$ is self-adjoint. In the complex case, self-adjointness actually follows from the above. But not in the real case.

More precisely, one defines the following partial order on self-adjoint operators: $M\leq N$ if $(Mx,x)\leq (Nx,x)$ for every $x\in H$. It is then equivalent to $N-M$ being a positive operator. And this is in turn equivalent to the fact that the spectrum of $N-M$ be contained in $[0,+\infty)$.

So in your case, this double inequality is equivalent to the spectrum of $M$ being contained in $[0,1]$.